Doubt regarding the existence of a life form unrelated to all the other life forms
Primitive life on earth began from a mixture of complex organic compounds which were formed millions of years ago which evolved and gave rise to all the current species. So is it possible that another form of life may have evolved in the past or may be evolving currently from a different mixture of organic compounds leading to organisms simple or complex totally different from the organisms we know having no common ancestry?

Welcome to SE Biology. Please finish reading the [Tour] to find out how this site works, and the Help on asking questions. One thing you should check before posting is whether a similar question has been asked before, by using the search facility. If you had done this you would find that there are several variants on your question. Also note that the Indian English “doubt” is not British or International English. Use “question”.
